# TestFlight Export Compliance internal testers

Tags: ios, testflight

i want to distribute my app within an internal test group via TestFlight. Do I have to fullfill export compliance requirements? I don‘t want to upload this app to external testers or the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will also ask you to reconfirm when you upload subsequent builds.

Comment: Yes, it will ask me that is right. But do i have to think about this topic although it is internal ?

Comment: It depends where your internal users are located. If they are outside the US it will still be considered an export so you will have to comply.

Comment: Ok thanks! I‘m from Europe and this topic seems very complicated. If my App just have GPS functionalities then I don‘t have to fullfill the requirements, right? This app doesn‘t exist any connections to a webserver but nevertheless I‘m unsure in regards to possible app configuration or so on.

Comment: Correct. If your app doesn't use any encryption then you can choose the no encryption option. Common uses of encryption include HTTPS connections, shared key connections and storing data in the keychain.